# default password for apache XAMPP user daemon?

Tags: apache, xampp

In my httpd.conf file, my apache is running as user daemon, group daemon. I don't recall setting this account up with a password, and a blank password doesn't let me in. Does anyone know how I gain access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not best practice, better option would be:

1.Create your content

2.Move it to the webroot with sudo, (`sudo mv /currentpath /webrootpath`)

3.Then set the webserver user as the owner with  `sudo chown -R daemon: daemon /path/to/your/webroot`

In order to actually access the daemon user you would need to set a password with:

1. `sudo passwd daemon`
   also will likely need to set a shell for the user as it is NOT supposed to be logged in (or have many permissions):
2. `chsh -s /bin/bash daemon` or edit the /etc/passwd file entry for the user to set shell directly.

...Hope that helps.